# Unable to login in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

```
$(document).ready(function () {
debugger;
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        beforeSend: function (request) {
        // request.setRequestHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication"
        // , "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>*******</Username><Password>****** </Password>    <IntegratorKey>******</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>");
        request.setRequestHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication"
        ,"{\"Username\":\"********\",\"Password\":\"*****\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"*******\"}");
        },
        url: "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?    api_password=false&include_account_id_guid=tr...
        success: function (r) {
            debugger;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

I am using above to login, I get response code 200.. But response is always blank .Even if I give wrong password, still it gives 200.
Moreover Under API section Activate In part is blank.. Please suggest solution

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: The error “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource” indicates that DocuSign is not accessable through jQuery/AJAX. You're going to want to do your login request through another language and pass the variables through to JS

Answer (score 6):

The error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` indicates that DocuSign is not accessable through jQuery/AJAX. You're going to want to do your login request through another language and pass the variables through to JS

**Here is more details on the answer I provided above in PHP.**

This was a quick example I just threw together to show the process that should be done, it will have to be modified to fit your needs (especially if you're not using PHP).

### HTML page:

```
<div id='divBox'>Logging into DocuSign...</div>
<script src="js/jQuery2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "script.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( data ){
      if(!data.errorCode)
      {
        $('#divBox').html('Logged Into ' + data.name + ' (' + data.accountId + ') account!');
      }else{
        $('#divBox').html('Failed to Login!<br>Error: ' + data.errorCode);
      }
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("error");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

### Script.php:

```
<?
$email = "ENTER EMAIL HERE";
$password = "ENTER PASSWORD HERE";
$integratorKey = "ENTER INTEGRATOR KEY HERE";

$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?include_account_id_guid=true";
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($status==200){
  $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
  print_r(json_encode($response['loginAccounts'][0]));
}else{
  print_r($json_response);
}
```