# i got a 400 bad request error, While sending the document by using the DocuSign rest api

Tags: jquery, docusignapi

I am new to call the document send Docusign REST API and using the document free docusign IDs, while calling the document send DocuSign REST API, getting BAD 400 request error and it's showing the error message `"error-code": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR"` and `"message": "Non-static method requires a target`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
method  : 'POST',
crossDomain : true,
headers: {
"X-DocuSign-Authentication":
"{\"Username\":\"username\",\"Password\":\"password\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"HEWL-dadabbac-6614-\"}"  },
body: 
{
  "emailBlurb": "DocuSign",
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign",
  "status": "Sent",
  "templateId": "738411FD-73BD-4CE8-9BE2-D944943FE3DE",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "roleName": "signer"
    }
  ]
},

success: function(result){
  var len = result.length;
 alert("Success");
},
 error: function(result){
    alert("Please Checkit Once..... !");
},
 error: function(result){
    alert("Please Checkit Once..... !");
},
});
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on but the "Non-static method requires a target" error message seems to be coming from C# which suggests a problem on the receiving end (which I assume is DoguSign). Do you send that request to Docusign directly or do you somehow pass it through a C# application of yours?

Comment: Hi Max , Thanks for your replay, i am trying to send the document through Docusign portal, here i am using the jquery/java script functionality to call REST API... i am able to send the document successfully from docusing portal, if i try to call the same rest api( which one send the document to the respective users) by using jquery/javascript, its showing the error.. could you please check if any thing is require to pass to the API...

Comment: Can you please post the code you use in the case of the portal? And can you include a link to it so we can look at it?

Answer (score 1):

FYI - DocuSign does not support CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), so you'll need to make backend API requests to access DocuSign's core platform.  See this post including comments:

[Unable to login in Docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518778/unable-to-login-in-docusign)

Additionally, with regards to your specific 400 - Bad Request I believe it's because you are not specifying any recipient information.  You are setting a template role but not assigning an actual recipient to it.  Try altering your `templateRoles` structure so that it's something like this:

```
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "roleName": "signer",
        "email": "john@email.com",
        "Name": "John Dow",
    }
```

Comment: Hi Argin, Thanks for your respons, i am able to get the login information successfully, envalope send API is only showing the 400 error .. remaining API'S are working fine... I made the some changes in my google chrome browser properties for your specified error...

Comment: Hi Kumar, I edited my post as I think I see the problem in your request.  Please test and let me know... Thx.